# Implementing Peterson's Algorithm for Mutual Exclusive in Eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, distributed-computing, mutual-exclusion

I am following the book **Concurrent and Distributed Computing in Java** by *Vijay K. Garg* and am having some issue with Peterson's Algorithm.

Lock interface:

```
public interface Lock {
    public void requestCS(int pid);
    public void releaseCS(int pid);
}
```

Peterson's algorithm:

```
public class PetersonAlgorithm implements Lock {

    boolean wantCS[] = {false, false};
    int turn = 1;

    @Override
    public void requestCS(int i) {
        int j = 1 - i;
        wantCS[i] = true;
        turn = j;
        while (wantCS[j] && turn == j) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseCS(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wantCS[i] = false;
    }
}
```

The two classes should be fine, but when I test it on Eclipse with the code

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TestMutualExclusive extends Thread {

    int myId;
    Lock lock;
    Random r = new Random();

    public TestMutualExclusive(int id, Lock lock) {
        myId = id;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    void nonCriticalSection() {
        System.out.println(myId + " is not in CS");
        Util.mySleep(r.nextInt(1000));
    }

    void CriticalSection() {
        System.out.println(myId + " is in CS ****");
        Util.mySleep(r.nextInt(1000));
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            lock.requestCS(myId);
            CriticalSection();
            lock.releaseCS(myId);
            nonCriticalSection();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        TestMutualExclusive t[] = new TestMutualExclusive[N];
        Lock lock = new PetersonAlgorithm();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            t[i] = new TestMutualExclusive(i, lock);
            t[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing came out is

```
0 is in CS ****
0 is not in CS
```

Instead of 0 and 1 alternatively entering the critical section. What is the problem?

UPD1: N is the number of threads I want to run
UPD2: Apparently if I add a mySleep function it works, but I still don't know why.

```
public class PetersonAlgorithm implements Lock {

    boolean wantCS[] = {false, false};
    int turn = 1;

    @Override
    public void requestCS(int i) {
        int j = 1 - i;
        wantCS[i] = true;
        turn = j;
        while (wantCS[j] && turn == j) Util.mySleep(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseCS(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wantCS[i] = false;
    }
}
```

UPD3: mySleep is a function that takes in time as an argument to stall the thread.

UPD4: the problem was that `turn` variable is not volatile. After setting it to volatile, now it has two variables entering the critical section at once. How do I fix it?

Comment: What is `N`?  You don't tell us what argument you gave the program.

Comment: Also, JavaScript is not Java, so please don't use a "JavaScript snippet" icon to enter Java code.

Comment: Also, what is `Util.mySleep`?  That could make a huge difference.

Comment: OK, I haven't tested this or tried to analyze all the code, but `while (wantCS[j] && turn == j) ;` looks like a problem.  First of all, it could go into an infinite loop and never let any other thread execute.  When you have multiple threads running on a single system, either a thread that's running has to do something that allows other threads to run (which this statement doesn't), or the JVM has to implement some kind of time-slicing where it lets a thread run for a certain amount of time and then allows another thread to run ... and I don't know if the typical JVM does that. ...

Comment: ... Second, even if another thread did break in and change `turn`, the `while` statement might not notice it, because you didn't declare `turn` to be `volatile`.  If it's `volatile`, the code makes sure to read it every time it's used.  If not, the compiler might do some analysis and decide that `turn` couldn't have possibly changed so it doesn't have to reread it.

Comment: That explains the problem. Thanks!